# Trouble setting up nginx to act as https server infront of backend servers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a backend server on http (on some IP), which is not intended to be accessed directly. I have setup another nginx server on a different machine, and used Let's Encrypt certbot to setup an ssl certificate on this machine

```
sudo apt-get install -y nginx
sudo certbot --nginx
```

Now, what I am hoping to achieve is - any request from client on https (port 443) should be redirected to my backend server on port 80.

Do I setup reverse_proxy in this case as explained here - https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Or, do I setup TLS termination on nginx as explained here - https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/terminating-ssl-http/

If I need both, what should my configurations look like?

my current reverse-proxy.conf -

```
server {
    listen 443;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<backend-ip-address>;
    }
}
```

which doesn't work. My configtest on nginx always fail too -

```
service nginx configtest
 * Testing nginx configuration                                                                                   [fail]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
PS: whithout reverse-proxy.conf or any redirection, default nginx server worked well on https. This shows that let's encrypt worked correctly.

Error messages in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` -

```
2022/01/23 20:00:04 [notice] 3005#3005: signal process started
2022/01/23 20:00:06 [notice] 3007#3007: signal process started
2022/01/23 20:01:31 [crit] 3008#3008: *23 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 5.8.10.202, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2022/01/23 20:05:22 [crit] 3008#3008: *54 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.231.247, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2022/01/23 20:09:02 [crit] 3008#3008: *69 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.232.189, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

**Edit: Fixed the issue**

I just had to add a few entries in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (**Make sure you are not missing ending semi-colons**)

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name <domain-name>;
        ssl_certificate <path-to-fullchain.pem>;
        ssl_certificate_key <path-to-privkey.pem>;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://<downstream-ip>;
        }
}
```

And make sure no reverse-proxy.conf is setup in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Then run

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl status nginx
```

to verify if everything is working fine.

Comment: what error messages do you get? what does >doesn't work mean?

Comment: Updated error logs

Comment: What it means is, when accessing my domain from browser (after adding reverse-proxy.conf) the browser shows this -

This site can’t provide a secure connection <my-domain>.com sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: I haven't touched any other configuration (for example /etc/nginx/nginx.conf etc) yet. Also unlinked default - sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

Comment: @zookastos add `ssl` flag to the `listen` directive: `listen 443 ssl;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky: Sorry. that didn't work either.

Comment: Do, I also need to specify ssl cert path to nginx server?

Comment: @zookastos Of course SSL won't work without `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` directives. Nginx won't even start without them when `ssl` flag is specified.

Comment: Okay, I figured that in the meanwhile, and added the configs properly in reverse-proxy.conf. Now my service nginx configtest pass. But still I keep getting the same error. Probably a stupid question: Do I define all this ssl related config in nginx.conf or in sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf. Sorry, I am new to nginx. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking

Comment: nvm; I was missing semi-colon at the end of my statements, plus I also figured that these settings need to go into nginx.conf, not in reverse-proxy.conf in sites-available. Thanks for help @IvanShatsky